# Why does this mysql function keep returning zero value?

Tags: mysql, function

so this is the code

```
CREATE FUNCTION smc()   RETURNS FLOAT
  DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
DECLARE w1 FLOAT;
DECLARE w2 FLOAT;
DECLARE qd FLOAT;
DECLARE hasil FLOAT;

SET w1      = "SELECT TRUNCATE(SQRT(SUM((w1*w1))),2) FROM tb_term";
SET w2      =   "SELECT TRUNCATE(SQRT(SUM((w2*w2))),2) FROM tb_term";
SET qd      =   "SELECT TRUNCATE(SUM(w1*w2),2) FROM tb_term";
SET hasil   =   (qd/(w1*w2));   
RETURN hasil; END;
```

it keep return null value. when i return w1,w2 or qd it return 0 value. what's wrong ?
thanks before.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring your `w1`, `w2`, and `qd` variables as FLOAT but you're assigning strings to them; the result is that you get 0.0 in all three. Then you assign `0.0/0.0` to `hasil` and dividing by zero gives you a NULL.

I think you're looking for

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(SQRT(SUM((w1*w1))),2) into w1 FROM tb_term;
SELECT TRUNCATE(SQRT(SUM((w2*w2))),2) into w2 FROM tb_term;
SELECT TRUNCATE(SUM(w1*w2),2) into qd FROM tb_term;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite your function in this way -

```
CREATE FUNCTION smc()
RETURNS FLOAT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE w1    FLOAT;
  DECLARE w2    FLOAT;
  DECLARE qd    FLOAT;
  DECLARE hasil FLOAT;

  SELECT truncate(sqrt(sum((w1 * w1))), 2) INTO w1 FROM tb_term;
  SELECT truncate(sqrt(sum((w2 * w2))), 2) INTO w2 FROM tb_term;
  SELECT truncate(sum(w1 * w2), 2) INTO qd FROM tb_term;
  SET hasil = (qd / (w1 * w2));
  RETURN hasil;
END
```

And rename declared variables w1, w2, they should not be the same as field names.

Answer (score 1):

Set statement does not assign query result to the variable. In this case it just assign the query string. You can do this by [SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) statement.

```
SELECT 
     TRUNCATE(SQRT(SUM((w1*w1))),2),
     TRUNCATE(SQRT(SUM((w2*w2))),2),
     TRUNCATE(SUM(w1*w2),2)  
INTO w1, w2, qd 
FROM tb_term
```

Comment: @user1297348 Did you see the update? You can do it in *one* single query.